# Random next activity button

Tags: random, android-intent, android-activity

I am really new to coding. So If I explain bad or do dumb mistakes just tell me, so I can get better.

Anyways. I am creating a game and my intention is to make a button open a random activity.
Like this:
activity1 -> activity5 -> activity4 ->activity 18 and so on. Without opening the same activity that has already been played. But now my issue is that I have 20 activities, but sometimes it only appears 12 before my app says "Game Over". How can I make sure its always gonna load max activites?
thanx.

My code works like this:

**Mainactivity.class**

```
     int r = new Random().nextInt(activitylist.size());
            Class activity = activitylist.remove(r);

            switch (r) {
                case 1:
                    activity = defransman.class;
                    activitylist.remove(defransman.class);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    activity = crazycaps.class;
                    activitylist.remove(crazycaps.class);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    activity = max.class;
                    activitylist.remove(max.class);
                    break;
                case 4:
                    activity = michael.class;
                    activitylist.remove(michael.class);
                    break;
                case 5:
                    activity = youngest.class;
                    activitylist.remove(youngest.class);
                    break;
                case 6:
                    activity = driverlincense.class;
                    activitylist.remove(driverlincense.class);
                    break;

            }

            Intent startgame = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
            startgame.putExtra("ACTIVITY_LIST", activitylist);
            startActivity(startgame);

        }
    });
}
```

}

**Activity2.class:**

public class bestclothes extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_bestclothes);

    Button nextpage = findViewById(R.id.BTBesteKleren);
    nextpage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            ArrayList<Class> aktivitet = new ArrayList<>();
            Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
            aktivitet = (ArrayList<Class>) extras.get("ACTIVITY_LIST");

            if (aktivitet.size() ==0) {
                Toast.makeText(bestclothes.this, "Game over", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            } else {
                int r = new Random().nextInt(aktivitet.size());
                Class activity = aktivitet.remove(r);

                switch (r) {
                    case 1:
                        activity = aktivitet.get(0);
                        aktivitet.remove(0);
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        activity = aktivitet.get(1);
                        aktivitet.remove(1);
                        break;
                    case  3:
                        activity = aktivitet.get(2);
                        aktivitet.remove(2);
                        break;
                    case 4:
                        activity = aktivitet.get(3);
                        aktivitet.remove(3);
                        break;
                    case 5:
                        activity = aktivitet.get(4);
                        aktivitet.remove(4);
                        break;
                    case 6:
                        activity = aktivitet.get(5);
                        aktivitet.remove(5);
                        break;  
}  
Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), activity);
                intent.putExtra("ACTIVITY_LIST", aktivitet);
                startActivity(intent);
```

and so on. I

Answer (score 0):

Stop removing activities from the list as you did in every switch cases.

Instead of it, save the position of every opened activity in some arraylist, then check if arraylist contains any position that user has already opened using `arrayList.contains(position)`.

It will return true if arraylist contains a previously visited activity position. If arraylist contains that position, then generate a random number again within the same range.

Put this logic in all switch cases & you will only get the activity that is not opened previously. :)